# Token is automatically changing on every request

Tags: django, jwt, token, access-token, refresh-token

I get access and refresh token after logging in by following code.

```
class Employee_Login(APIView):
permission_classes=[AllowAny]
employee_login_data = serializers.employee_login_serializer

def post(self,request):
    try:
        employee_data = self.employee_login_data(data=request.data)
        employee_data.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        data = employee_data.validated_data

        employee = authenticate(request,email=data.get('email'), password= data.get('password'))

        if not employee:
            return Http404("Employee not found")
        
        if not employee.is_verified:
            raise ForbiddenException("Employee is not verified")
        
        payloads = {
            "user": "admin" if employee.is_admin and employee.is_verified and employee.is_staff
                    else "staff" if employee.is_staff and employee.is_verified
                    else ""
        }

        employee_detail = {
            "name":employee.name,
            "email":employee.email,
            "type":"admin" if employee.is_admin and employee.is_staff and employee.is_verified 
                        else "staff" if employee.is_admin and employee.is_verified
                        else ""
        }

        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(employee)
        refresh.payload.update(payloads)

        acess_token = str(refresh.access_token)
        refresh_token = str(refresh)

        


        return Response({"success":True, 
                         "data":employee_detail, 
                         "token":{"access":acess_token,"refresh":refresh_token}})
    except Exception as e:
        return Response({"success":False,"message":str(e)})
```

The problem is, when I use the access token obtained from above code in below custom permission class

class AdminPermission(permissions.BasePermission):

```
def has_permission(self, request, view):

    print("Here",AccessToken(request.auth).payload)
    
    STAFF_METHODS = ['GET','POST','PATCH']
    USER_METHODS = ['GET']
    
    if request.method in USER_METHODS:
        return True
    
    print(AccessToken(request.auth))
        
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
    
        if request.user.is_admin and request.user.is_staff and request.user.is_verified:
            return True
        
        if not request.user.is_admin and request.user.is_staff and request.user.is_verified and request.method in STAFF_METHODS: 
            return True
    
    return False
```

The `print(AccessToken(request.auth))` is printing different token than the token that I passed from request. And it is printing different things in every request.

I am frustrated by this and couldn't figure out where I went wrong. Please help me.

Comment: Are you using JWT?

Comment: If so, it probably because of ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS setting. Ref : - https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html